# When executing curl statement getting error - curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL

Tags: curl

When executng below command

```
curl --user 3b11253746992b605ceb7a4:c026c49ef93334a5f98b4fd4e20c14329c4f0aaa4e6b45b78b76ec367425b6bef8c9dfbd \
-F 'files[]=@calcEngine.csv' https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/folders/649a812e3506d803df412854/files
```

getting curl:

```
(3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

When executng below command  in bash

```
curl --user 3b11253746992b605ceb7a4:c026c49ef93334a5f98b4fd4e20c14329c4f0aaa4e6b45b78b76ec367425b6bef8c9dfbd \
-F 'files[]=@calcEngine.csv' https://a.blazemeter.com/api/v4/folders/649a812e3506d803df412854/files
```

getting curl:

```
 (3) Illegal characters found in URL
```

Comment: Please add a tag for the programming environment that causes this problem. I get a different error message when I run your command in `bash`. .... ALSO ... Is there really a `:` char in your userID? Good luck.

Comment: The text after the `:` is a password. You might want to remove it from the question.